# How to trigger useEffect before render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using axios to fetch data and then want to render the component. For that, I have loading which gets set to true when fetching and to false when all the data has come.
But I am getting error. Is there a way to trigger useEffect before rendering of component ?

Following is the code:

**GithubReducer.js**

```
import {
  SET_USERS,
  CLEAR_USERS,
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_USER,
  CLEAR_USER,
} from "../types";

const GithubReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USERS: {
      return { ...state, users: action.payload };
    }

    case CLEAR_USERS: {
      return { ...state, users: [] };
    }

    case SET_LOADING: {
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload };
    }

    case SET_USER: {
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    }

    case CLEAR_USER: {
      return { ...state, user: null };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default GithubReducer;
```

**GithubState.js**

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  SET_USERS,
  CLEAR_USERS,
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_USER,
  CLEAR_USER,
} from "../types";

import GithubReducer from "./GithubReducer";
import GithubContext from "./GithubContext";

const GithubState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
    user: null,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(GithubReducer, initialState);

  const setLoading = (val) => dispatch({ type: SET_LOADING, payload: val });

  const getGithubUsers = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_USER });

    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users`);

    dispatch({
      type: SET_USERS,
      payload: res.data,
    });

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const clearUsers = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_USERS });
  };

  const searchUsersWithName = async (username) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${username}`
    );

    dispatch({ type: SET_USERS, payload: res.data.items });
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const fetchGithubUserProfile = async (username) => {
    setLoading(true);

    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);

    dispatch({ type: SET_USER, payload: res.data });
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <GithubContext.Provider
      value={{
        getGithubUsers,
        clearUsers,
        searchUsersWithName,
        fetchGithubUserProfile,
        users: state.users,
        loading: state.loading,
        user: state.user,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </GithubContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GithubState;
```

**User.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import GithubContext from "../../context/github/GithubContext";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";

const User = () => {
  const { fetchGithubUserProfile, user, loading } = useContext(GithubContext);
  const { username } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGithubUserProfile(username);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <Spinner />;
  else {
    return (
      <div className="user">
        <button>Go Back</button>
        <section className="about">{user.login}</section>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default User;
```

And, this is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'login')
User
D:/anubh/Desktop/github-finder/src/components/users/User.js:21
  18 |   return (
  19 |     <div className="user">
  20 |       <button>Go Back</button>
> 21 |       <section className="about">{user.login}</section>
     | ^  22 |     </div>
  23 |   );
  24 | }
```

Comment: The issue isn't with your data loading, it's with your initial state. Why isn't loading == true when the component is first mounted? You haven't fetched the data yet so it should be true. Then your code would be returning the spinner rather than erroring.

Comment: If you see in fetchGithubUserProfile function I am setting the value of loading to true

Comment: But you're not calling the function until your effect fires (after the component is mounted), and if it's mounted with loading=false (which it is from your initial state) it will be returning the div where you're trying to access user.login and user is null

Comment: You're mistakenly assuming that the code in your useEffect is executed before the code in your return. Just because it appears higher in the code is not indicative of execution order. If you set loading to true in your initial state I believe your code would work properly

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. You can't. useEffect runs after `componentDidMount`, or after the JSX has been rendered.

Here is a solution. Render your JSX conditionally depending on state, which you can set once your data is retrieved.

```js
return (
   {data ? <MyComponent /> : null}
)
```

Comment: For that I am using loading....why is it not working ?